# Groovy Sql Query Returning Date Column as String

Tags: java, sql, date, groovy

I have a groovy class that is responsible for running a query against a sql database table and extracting some data from the results to build a DTO. The database column I am interested in is called 'release_date' is of type (date,null). I was expecting the results to return a java.util.Date object but instead I am getting a java.lang.String. The strange thing is, if I change the type of the column to a datetime it seems to work correctly.

Is this expected behaviour from groovy? Is there a way to get it to return a Date object without having to change the column of the database?

**My Groovy Code:**

```
Sql opticsSql=myDb;

def run(Map<Long, OriginalDateDTO> dtoMap) {
def query = """select p.id,p.release_date as planned from releases p; """;
opticsSql.eachRow(query.toString()) { val->
            Long id = val.id;
            Date planned = val.planned;
            Map localMap = dtoMap;
            Boolean hasKey = localMap.containsKey(id);
            if(hasKey) {
                dtoMap.get(id).originalPlannedDate = planned;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Jdbc driver is responsible for type conversion. Groovy just returns the values from jdbc.

Comment: Exactly what data type is the database column? And what kind of database engine? Telling us "'release_date' is of type (date,null)" is not enough.

Comment: FYI, both `Date` classes are terribly flawed in design. They were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by `Instant` and `LocalDate`.